# How to set object fields from a HashMap directly in android

Tags: java, android, reflection, hashmap, mapping

I want to assign all vales from `hashMap` to `myObject`:

```
Map <String, Object> hashMap;

UserdefinedClass myObject;
```

Is there any library or direct approach available?

Comment: Iterate over the map and fetch values

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay :) , but am looking for a library or a direct approach.

Comment: you don't need library for this. If it's a huge list, you can use mappers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328146/java-simple-way-to-put-linkedhashmap-keys-values-into-respective-lists

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Add values to Object(Entity class).
Step 2: Add Object to Hashmap as a value wrt Key.
Step 3: Get the Object from HasMap and use iterator to iterate the values.

```
Iterator iterator = meMap.keySet().iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
String key=(String)iterator.next();
String value=(String)meMap.get(key);
}
```

Fell free to ask for any query.

Comment: what if the Hashmap is in a LinkedHashMap structure ?

Comment: So you need to iterate LinkedHashMap to get the Hashmap, iterate Hashmap to get the Object. Rest if you can share the snippet of the code, it will be help full to give the appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the hash map and then do whatever you want...

```
Iterator<Entry<String,Object>> iterator = hashMap.entrySet().iterator();

        while(iterator.hasNext()){

            set = iterator.next();
            Object val = set.getValue();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let'assume this your Hashmap

```
Map <String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
```

And this is your class object where you want to assign the values from hashmap.

```
List<UserdefinedClass> myObject = new ArrayList<UserdefinedClass>();
```

Now, you need to iterate through the hashmap and get the value, type cast it and store it in myObject list.

```
 Iterator it = hashMap.entrySet().iterator();
 while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        myObject.add((UserdefinedClass)pair.getValue());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Convert a Map to a POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37822085/1028256)

`Jackson` can be used in android project for sure. `BeanUtils` are told to be much faster, but I have no experience with it on Android. High chances are that it can be used as well.